# How to query Standard field's fieldId

Tags: metadata, fields, tooling-api

The standard field Ids for Opportunity standard fields are opp1, opp2, opp3... and so on.

Is there a way to query them using JS connection sdk or any tooling API available to query these.

The use case is,
I need them to create link to that can prepopulate opportunity fields when navigated.

Example. https://my.salesforce.com/006/e?opp7=123

This populates Amount field with 123, I cannot hard code opp7 because my use case is dynamic, and it has to be populate conditionally.

So I want to know if there is any way to query them either via JS connection API on sforce, or any other means.

Comment: URL hacks are not the supported approach for prepopulating with default field values, have you looked into using the `defaultFieldValues` mechanism with actions or a custom component? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_dfv.htm

Comment: It lightning the url hacks are possible via fieldName. In classic its possible with fieldIds too, but the issues is, I could not find any API that can give me fieldIds for standard fields, 
opp7 for amount field in opportunity,

Comment: I never said this was impossible. What I said is that it's not the supported approach for doing prepopulation of field values on new records.